# Route 53 how can I set different records for multi level wildcard subdomains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm using AWS Route 53 and I have two A records as follows:

```
*.domain.com - resource1
*.*.domain.com - resource2
```

At the moment the are both matching resource 1, what I want is for the two level wildcard to match resource 2 and the single level wildcard to match resource 1., and ideally if there is a 3rd or 4th level to not match any.

Is this possible?

Essentially I'm trying to point the 2 level subdomain at my staging server:

```
company1.domain.com
company2.stagingserver.domain.com
```

Comment: Why not just `*.stagingserver.domain.com` for the second record?

Comment: stagingserver changes based on the branch name of the feature we are using. It always points to the same server that uses apache dynamic virtual hosting, i.e `company.featurebranch.domain.com`